What is the difference between Aristotelian dialectic and Hegelian dialectic?
What is the difference between Aristotelian dialectic and Hegelian dialectic?
cf. "Is Hegelian dialectic only binary?"

Please give a definition of Aristotelian dialectic, thanks. - As far as I know "dialegesthai" has been coined and recommended by Plato as the method of a philosophical dialogue.

@Conifold Does Hegelian dialectic simply recognize that there may be elements in truth/overlap in seemingly opposing theses?

No, Hegel does not seek to reconcile the opposites, nor does he think that they are only "seeming" and can be reconciled. His idea is more radical, to overthrow the framework that produces them and to replace it with a novel "higher" one that "sublates" them as limited perspectives. This is supposed to be a creative breakthrough to a new conception beyond any elements present at the level of the opposites.

@Conifold So he thinks contradictions can be resolved by changing logic ("the framework")? Is that what he means?

"The framework" is a conceptual framework, not just logic and not necessarily involving logic at all. His 'contradictions' (opposites) are typically not formal logical contradictions, but he is not interested in resolving them in the usual sense anyway (like making subtle distinctions). That said, he did advocate 'changing logic', but not for sublating any particular opposites, but rather because "formal" logic and its categories do not provide expressive means for generating and developing new concepts generally. Hegelian resolving is in replacing old concepts altogether.

As SEP's entry shows, the correct background is Plato's dialectic.

From Conifold:

Aristotle's dialectic is an argumentative dialog aimed at refuting opponent's position based on mutually accepted premises. Hegel's dialectic is a philosophical method of conceptual development through overcoming 'contradictions' (oppositions) and subsuming them at a higher level. Hegel criticized classical dialectic for going nowhere once the positions are refuted, while his (supposedly) gives a way of moving beyond them to superior ones

